# Why android:onTextChanged databinding removed from edittext?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

recently I see this warning from my Edittext:

`unknown attribute android:onTextChanged`

and no longer text shown in my **ViewModel** data

What is the alternative way to retrieve text from Edittext in databinding?

Comment: In your xml file give the attribute android:text="@={your_variable}". When the text in the EditText will be changed, the new value will be saved to your_variable.

Comment: Found out the problem, I forget to give ViewModel to my databinding class.

Comment: @AmirHosseinGhasemi Can you elaborate on what you mean by this?  I have this problem and am looking for a solution.  Thanks!

Comment: @rexar5 Your edittext value should be filled before using, for example if you use `model.text` make sure the model is filled in the code via `binding.model = yourModel` in order to work.

Comment: Thank you!  It turns out my problem was I had my VM method take a String instead of a CharSequence.  In case anyone else sees this.